# eslint prettier: commas on objects?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I seem to have a problem with ESlint & Prettier in Vscode. As far as I can tell everything is configured correctly, where <;> will be added on save, but not <,> for objects.

[image]

Eslint Config has:

`

```
    "comma-dangle": [
        1,
        {
            "objects": "always",
            "arrays": "ignore",
            "imports": "ignore",
            "exports": "ignore",
            "functions": "ignore"
        }
    ],`
```

prettier config has `"trailingComma": "es5",`

So I'm not sure why it isn't working correctly, and can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

the comma to be placed automatically when I save the document like semi colon.

Comment: [`comma-dangle`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/comma-dangle) is about the optional, trailing comma for the last property of an object definition. You're wanting something different- fixing missing commas after any property of an object definition.

Comment: oh i see. Is comma style the rule I want to use?

Comment: I have no idea. How often is this actually a problem for you that you want to automate fixing it? Is it really so hard to write a comma in the right place manually? You'll already get syntax errors to notify you of any places that are missing them. I can't imagine why this would be problematic enough to warrant wanting a tool to fix it.

Comment: I'm not even asking for a tool. I thought I had it configured incorrectly.

Comment: They way the question is posed is not consistent with your self-answer. You have not yet made it clear what you are actually looking for as you specified in your self answer. You do not get a free pass on writing a good question when you write a self-answer. Please rectify.

Comment: I don't see a reason to change it. The question was fine, and came from my position of understanding. You knew what I was asking. "You're wanting something different- fixing missing commas after any property of an object definition."

After my reply you said "I have no idea." If you didn't actually have the answer why did you post to begin with?

You either intentionally obfuscated the answer. The correct answer would have been "you can't do that with eslint." End of discussion. Right now you're pulling at straws trying to make me look bad, but all you're doing is making yourself look bad.

Comment: No- as far as I can tell, what your self-answer is answering is a different question. Your first comment to my answer also indicates this inconsistency in what your post asks about and what you seem to want. The extension adds commas on starting a new line- not on invoking the format action. Your question is about the format action (more specifically, you ask about format-on-save, which generalizes to the format action).

Answer (score 0):

> So I'm not sure why it isn't working correctly, and can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

If that's all you're wondering about, the reason why it's not working correctly is because that's because [`comma-dangle`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/comma-dangle) is about the optional, trailing comma for the last property of an object definition. Also related is Prettier's [`trailing-commas`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#trailing-commas) option. You're wanting something different- fixing missing commas after any property of an object definition.

TL;DR the thing you're trying to use doesn't do the thing you want because that's the way it is.

Comment: Whenever I hit enter, and go down a line with most other lines, the semicolon is added automatically. I assumed commas would work the same way. Since it didn't I thought I had it configured incorrectly. I wasn't asking for a tool. The condescending tone isn't necessary. I found an extension that does what I wanted to do. Consistency is great

Comment: My tone is written with the intention of being matter-of-fact and not condescending. If you've found a solution you like better because hidden requirements that you haven't (yet) specified in your question post, you should update your question post with that information about your needs ([ask]), and then write up an answer post ([answer]).

Comment: @hifilo Semicolons are optional (more or less), and should "just" be added for consistency. Commas between object properties are not optional, missing them is a syntax error. It's not the job of an autoformatter to fix broken code.

Comment: @hifilo and are you sure that's _really_ what you want? What if you're writing an equation as an object-key's value, and you actually wanted to start a new line and put binary operator at the start of the new line to continue the expression? That's just one example. Wouldn't you then be annoyed that your tool is adding commas for you?

Answer (score 0):

While eslint & prettier can be setup to add `;` on save, `,` can not. You would think for the sake of consistency you could. The extension [auto insert comma](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LeonQin.auto-insert-comma) will accomplish that though, if (for whatever reason) the punctuation discontinuity stands out to you.